# How to color an Object3D Object in ThreeJs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, 3d

So I want to color an Object in my project. I am importing these Objects from a file, and want to color them by clicking at them.

So I tried this:

`let mat= (this.scene.children[4].getObjectByName(intersects[0].object.name)as THREE.Mesh).material.color.setHex("red");`
to color the object. I need to access the object as a Mesh because there is no way to color an Object3D(or at least i couldnt find a way to do so). But here it says *Property 'color' does not exist on type 'Material'.* There has to be a way to color the Object,  but I cant find it anywhere.I have also looked through the ThreeJs forums but I also couldnt find an answer there.

I am using Typescript to code my project, is that the problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Typescript is not a problem but you have to deep undestand classes and methods, otherwise your code will never run.

**First problem**: you can't define a variable "mat" like that

```
let mat = (this.scene.children[4].getObjectByName(intersects[0].object.name)as THREE.Mesh).material.color.setHex("red");
```

If you want to save a reference to the object's material you can do it like this:

```
let mat: MeshBasicMaterial = (this.scene.children[4].getObjectByName(intersects[0].object.name)as THREE.Mesh).material;
```

And the method setHex, it has no return type, read how setHex works here:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color

**Second problem**: setHex works with Hex color, "red" is not a color, it's a name used to describe a color. His hex code (for a pure red) is "FF0000" but in order to work with setHex method you have to write:

```
setHex(0xff0000)
```

**Third problem**: using casting in Typescript means that something is not done properly. Of course you can cast an Object3D to Mesh but you are accessing a "material" property without describing it. The default Type "Material" has no color property but his extensions like: MeshBasicMaterial or MeshStandardMaterial have it.

So to do what are you tring to do I think this code will works:

```
((this.scene.children[4].getObjectByName(intersects[0].object.name)as THREE.Mesh).material as THREE.MeshBasicMaterial).color.setHex(0xff0000);
```

Let me know if it works for you.